# APNS issue when opening Application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

When app is closed (not running in the background) and the phone receives an APNS the `didReceiveRemoteNotification` is not called.

If the app is not running in the phone's background, an an APNS message is received, clicking on the banner or pop-up notification opens up the app, but the `didReceiveRemoteNotification` delegate is not called.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**didReceiveRemoteNotification** gets called only when you are using the app (when the app is running) and if you want to perform some specif operation when user click on banner notification then in Appdelegate's **-(BOOL)application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions** check if it coming through notification

```
// Handle notification when app is quit
NSDictionary *notification = [launchOptions objectForKey:@"UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey"];

if (notification != nil) {

    [self handleNotificationsForApplication:application notification:notification];
}
```

And impelement the method **handleNotificationsForApplication:application notification:notification**

```
- (void)handleNotificationsForApplication:(UIApplication *)application notification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {

NSDictionary *data = [[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"data"];
NSString *type = [data objectForKey:@"type"];

if ([type isEqualToString:@"app_update"]) {

   // Show alert to do the update
}
else if ([type isEqualToString:@"new_chat"]) {

    imageData = data;

    if (application.applicationState != UIApplicationStateActive) {

        // Open chat view
    }
    else {

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:APP_NAME
                                                        message:[[userInfo valueForKey:@"aps"] valueForKey:@"alert"]
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert setTag:2];
        [alert show];
    }
}
}
```